# Yiic message generator not working yii1.1

Tags: php, yii

I'm trying to generate message traduction with this command:

```
yiic message message/config.php
```

it give me this result :

```
PHP Warning:  require_once(/var/www/dev.mysite.ch/yiic.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /yii/yii-1.1.14/framework/yiic on line 22
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/dev.mysite.ch/yiic.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /yii/yii-1.1.14/framework/yiic on line 22
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My file yiic was corrupt. I made a new one and it's working!

Answer (score -1):

maybe,you should do like this.
chmod 0777 yiic

Comment: Terrible and ignorant advice. This will allow *any* user to write to this file and is a huge security risk. This is how websites get hacked and start serving malware.